# JQuery: Send date to controller method

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send a date to my controller method using get, my JQuery runs and I can see the output from my console.logs and network tab in IE Debugger. My issue is that the date seams to be scrambled as it is sent and i just get null on the other end.

here is the URL for the GET Request (seams to be a large amount of added whitespace (not shown as whitespace is removed by the forum api when entered))

/Home/AjaxGetDataForDate?                            11/09/2014 10:25:38

How do i correct this so the data is passed?

My Jquery:

```
$("#basicModal2 tr").click(function () {
        var trdate1 = $(this).closest('tr').find(":nth-child(2n)").css("background", "#ff0000");
        var trdate = $(this).closest('tr').find(":nth-child(2n)").text();            
        alert(trdate)
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/AjaxGetDataForDate",
            data: trdate,
            datatype: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Succes!");
                var $detailDiv2 = $('#superdatadiv2');
                $detailDiv2.replaceWith(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("Error!");
            },
            complete: function () {

                $('#basicModal4').modal('show');
                console.log("Complete!");
            }
        });
    });
```

My Controller Method (After GET is sent filterdate should contain the date (instead contains null))

```
public ActionResult AjaxGetDataForDate(string filterdate)
    {
        var filterresults = from m in db2.ANDROID_BATTERY select m;

        filterresults = filterresults.Where(x => x.TEST_DATE.ToString().Contains(filterdate));                                          

        MasterModel model = new MasterModel();
        model.BatteryInfo = filterresults;          

        return GetAjaxData2(model);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `'filterdate'` name to the data in ajax call same as in your controller action parameter i.e. `'filterdate'` as shown below :

Instead of

```
 data: trdate,
```

Try

```
 data: { filterdate : trdate },
```

Comment: Talk about instant fix less than 1 min to reply :) Thanks kartikeya! the date is now passed but I'm concerned about the surrounding white space and \n's as shown below I believe this is polluting the result of the linq query, any suggestions ?

filterdate = "\n                            11/09/2014 10:25:38\n                        "

Does this get removed?

Comment: @Baggerz..,,just check when you are sending date as string from ajax request just remove unnecessary characters  and white spaces with `$.trim()` or you can use `decodeURIComponent` or `encodeURIComponent` while sending data with querystring and you can handle unwanted characters in controller action also.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
data: trdate,
```

with

```
data: {
        filterdate : trdate 
      },
```

in your `ajax` function call, as you had used `filterdate` in the `action method` of the `controller`.